# Running a program using Ant & Eclipse , Result is not same

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, java-7

When I run the below code using Eclipse it is working fine ( Able to stop the Service)
But If I run the code using Ant , the below code not able to stop the service.

jdk1.7.0_17
apache-ant-1.9.0

```
 Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "Sc",  "\\\\serverName", "STOP", "ServicenName" });   
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
 String line = null;  
 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
   System.out.println(line);  
 }
```

Please let me know the reason for this.

Adding URL for [build.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0E6eH6OaIsmTlpNdklWdlVTdXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you "run the code using Ant"? Can you show us the script?

Comment: Henry , Thanks for the response. I've added URL for build.xml file to the question.

Comment: Install Sysinternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Set a filter on the "Process Start" and "Process Exit" Operations. Compare the results of running the code in Eclipse and in running the code with Ant. This should clarify the source of the problems.